# How to add custom CSS to view?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am building an application in ExtJS 5.1 using Sencha Cmd.

I have the following view, located on `/Web/app/app/view/guard/apps/Launcher.js`:

```
Ext.define('Web.view.guard.apps.Launcher', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    xtype: 'widget.applauncher', 

    scale: 'large',
    border: false,
    icon: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg',

    iconAlign: 'top',
    iconCls: 'squareImg',
    bodyCls: 'launcher',

    handler : function() {
        var app = Ext.create('Web.view.desktop.window.Window', {
            title : this.text
        });
    }
});
```

And custom CSS defined on `/Web/app/sass/src/view/guard/apps/Launcher.scss`:

```
.squareImg {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

.launcher {
    padding: 12px;
}
```

And inspecting the elements using Chrome Developer Tools, I see the components have the classes, but they match with no CSS rules, and I can't find `squareImg` and `launcher` classes on the generated CSS. What is wrong?

Comment: Did you build the CSS? Run `sencha app build`.

Comment: Tried right now, no changes...

Comment: Can you check what all css files are generated after sencha build.. also check if you are refering the css generated by build

Comment: Part of the problem might be that the way Sencha Cmd combines the individual SASS files together works off the `requires` hierarchy.

You need, somewhere, to specify that your Launcher class is required by something - probably the main App class.

You should probably check that your Sass namespace is set to 'Web' - I think the default is 'Ext'.

Comment: @RobertWatkins That indeed worked! I added requires: `['Web.view.guard.apps.Launcher']`, to my `app/Application.js` file and now the CSS rules are applied. Also, the default workspace is the same as the name of the app generated by Sencha Cmd, so no problem there. If you're willing to write an answer, I can mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha CMD combines individual SASS files into one large SASS file. It determines which SASS files to include by parsing your JavaScript files to determine which files are required - the same way it builds the combined JS file.

If you use a custom ExtJS class, but don't "require" it, Sencha CMD won't detect that, and therefore won't include the corresponding SASS files when packaging the CSS.

(One way to detect if that is happening is to be alert for errors in the console about downloading classes synchronously)

Comment: I must add that besides that, browser's cache may also make it hard to identify whether the CSS was generated or not. It is a good practice to disable it while developing. On Chrome, simply open the Developer Tools ( `ctrl + shift + J`), go to `Network` tab and check `Disable cache`. It will disable the cache for this address only.

Comment: Indeed. I'm somewhat surprised that disabling caches isn't the default with the developer tools...